# Problemas con márgenes de tabla al usar jumbotron en vista movil

Tags: bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

Estimados colegas vengo con una duda y a la vez ayuda esto haciendo usando de `table` de `boostrap` pero al momento de generar la vista movil la tabla con el `jumbotron` se descuadra por decirlo así se coloca hacia la derecha, que podría estar realizando erróneamente?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    @page
@model DetalleModel
@{

}
<div class="container-fluid center">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 text-center">
        <table class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <tbody class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                <tr>
                    <th class="jumbotron" style="padding: 15px;">
                        <h1 class="display-4 font-weight-bold">@Model.MODEL_TRATAMIENTO.DataTratamiento.TRA_CONCEPTO</h1>
                        <p class="display-4">Información sobre Tratamiento </p>
                        <hr class="my-4">
                        <p class="font-weight-bold"> El Valor del Tratamiento es de :   @Model.MODEL_TRATAMIENTO.DataTratamiento.TRA_VALOR</p>
                        <p class="font-weight-bold">El Porcentaje de Descuento del Tratamiento es de : @Model.MODEL_TRATAMIENTO.DataTratamiento.TRA_POR_DESC %</p>
                        <p class="font-weight-bold">El Descuento del Tratamiento es de : @Model.MODEL_TRATAMIENTO.DataTratamiento.TRA_DESC</p>
                        <p class="font-weight-bold">El Total del Tratamiento es de : @Model.MODEL_TRATAMIENTO.DataTratamiento.TRA_TOTAL</p>
                        <form asp-area="Presupuesto" asp-page="Registro" method="post">
                            @{
                                var dataTratamiento = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.MODEL_TRATAMIENTO.DataTratamiento);
                            }
                            <input type="hidden" name="dataTratamiento" value="@dataTratamiento" />
                            <input type="submit" value="Editar" class="btn btn-success ">
                        </form>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Lectura obligatoria https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Lectura sugerida: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/introduction/ Dato adicional: Cada vez que tengas "clases col-", llevan un "row" en el elemento padre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una vez de verificar y recibir unas cuantas ayudas y sugerencias quedo el codigo de la manera en la que el cliente me lo pide.

```
    @page
@model DetalleModel
@{

}
<div class="container center">
    <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <div class="jumbotron" style="padding-bottom:0px; padding-top:0px; background-color:transparent; margin-bottom:2px;">
                                <h1 class="font-weight-bold" style="padding:15px;">@Model.MODEL_TRATAMIENTO.DataTratamiento.TRA_CONCEPTO</h1>
                            </div>
                            <blockquote class="blockquote text-center">
                                <footer class="display-4 blockquote-footer">Información sobre Tratamiento </footer>
                            </blockquote>
                            <hr class="my-4">
                            <p class="font-weight-bold"> El Valor del Tratamiento es de :   @Model.MODEL_TRATAMIENTO.DataTratamiento.TRA_VALOR</p>
                            <p class="font-weight-bold">El Porcentaje de Descuento del Tratamiento es de : @Model.MODEL_TRATAMIENTO.DataTratamiento.TRA_POR_DESC %</p>
                            <p class="font-weight-bold">El Descuento del Tratamiento es de : @Model.MODEL_TRATAMIENTO.DataTratamiento.TRA_DESC</p>
                            <p class="font-weight-bold">El Total del Tratamiento es de : @Model.MODEL_TRATAMIENTO.DataTratamiento.TRA_TOTAL</p>
                            <form asp-area="Presupuesto" asp-page="Registro" method="post">
                                @{
                                    var dataTratamiento = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.MODEL_TRATAMIENTO.DataTratamiento);
                                }
                                <input type="hidden" name="dataTratamiento" value="@dataTratamiento" />
                                <input type="submit" value="Editar" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                            </form>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Aquí como se ve al ejecutar el código.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]